# Tomcat и NIO connector

Tags: java, tomcat, netty

Правильно ли я понимаю, что до 8-ой версии Tomcat использовал BIO коннектор, то есть каждый пользовательский запрос выполнялся в новом потоке (ну или из thread-pool по maxSize), начиная с 8-ой версии по умолчанию стал NIO (событийно-ориентированная модель), когда выделяется один поток и идет обработка разных событий (SelectionKey). По идее должно быть меньше потоков

1. Почему при обращение к ресурсу (например, get /test)
   Thread.currentThread().getName() возвращает все время разные имена
   (разные потоки)? Я могу предположить, что все равно локально
   создается thread-pool, но с меньшим размером
2. Правильно ли я понимаю, что Tomcat использует свою реализацию коннектора NIO (я имею ввиду нативный java.nio), нежели абстракцию netty, потому что он вышел позже?

Comment: На оба вопроса ответ - да.